# Amazon RDS postgres Data wiped and can't connect to database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created an RDS Postgres instance. I'm new to RDS.

db host:

```
 demodb.xxxuxxvxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

db identifier:

```
demodb
```

Every tutorial says to connect with this URL:
`jdbc:postgresql://demodb.xxxuxxvxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/demodb`

but every time I do I get this error-

```
FATAl: database "demodb" does not exist.
```

I am able to connect using this:

```
 jdbc:postgresql://demodb.xxxuxxvxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres
```

Now, while I was excited to connect after I used SQL workbench to create tables and insert data into those tables, a few hours later all my tables and data were deleted/wiped/dropped. Why would this happen? and How can I prevent it from happening in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FATAl: database "demodb" does not exist.

`demodb` is db instance identifier. It is **NOT the name of your database** inside of PostgreSQL.

By default RDS PostgreSQL **does not create a database for you**. It seems to me that you haven't created an actual database when you setup your RDS PostgreSQL.

To create a database at RDS creation there is an option called `Initial database name` where you should specify the name of the database you want. Otherwise, no database is created, which is a **default behavior**:

[image]